# When to use Spring Prototype vs Request vs Session scope? Any real life example

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I want to know when should I exactly use the **prototype**, **request** and **session** scope in Spring? I have understood that **singleton** returns the same object instance if the bean is requested.

Then why should we consider other spring scopes?

Explanations with examples would help a lot to understand the need for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explanation of Spring bean scopes with associated examples:

**Prototype**

What-> it provides a different instance every time for each request
When-> your bean contains a state (i.e. object attributes) which you want to keep isolated, and you want to be sure it does not get re-used at the next request

**Request**

What-> it provides a different instance every time for each HTTP request, available only in the context of a Web Application
When-> your bean models an incoming entity (i.e. Product object) which you need to capture and process within that web request

**Session**

What-> it provides a different instance for each HTTP Session, available only in the context of a Web Application
When-> local caching associated to a specific user, for example a ShoppingBasket or a UserSession, you normally you call this a Stateful application

Answer (score 0):

Used in the backend to batch process millions of records.
Data had to be converted to XML and sent to a third party.
In one thread, we processed 10 objects. The next thread processed 10 objects. During multiple thread processing, we wanted to ensure that these data objects did not interfere with each other.